# It's possible to passing a ref to FormTokenField from parent component using forwardRef?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I have a `InspectorControls` component which include `FormTokenField` and I want to pass a ref to `FormTokenField` from parent component. In parent I have a button with `onClick` handle which will set focus to the field when button is clicked. To make this thing happen I've use `forwardRef`.

But I get following error message: Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `ForwardRef(ChildComponent)`.

Here's a example how my code looks like:

Parent component:

```
import ChildComponent from './child-component';

import { Fragment, useRef } from '@wordpress/element';
import { Button } from '@wordpress/components';
import { InspectorControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

const ParentComponent = ( { isSelected, ...props } ) => {
    const tokenFieldRef = useRef( null );

    const clickHandler = () => {
        tokenFieldRef.current.focus();
    };

    return (
        <Fragment>
            { isSelected && (
                <InspectorControls>
                    <ChildComponent
                        { ...props }
                        ref={ tokenFieldRef }
                    />
                </InspectorControls>
            ) }
            <Button
                isLink
                onClick={ () => clickHandler }
            >
                Click to focus field
            </Button>
            // ... here are other child components
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Child Component:

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import {
    PanelBody,
    FormTokenField,
} from '@wordpress/components';
import { forwardRef } from '@wordpress/element';

const suggestions = [
    __( 'Suggestion one', 'text-domain' ),
    __( 'Suggestion two', 'text-domain' ),
];

const ChildComponent = ( props, ref ) => {
    const {
        attributes,
        setAttributes,
    } = props;
    const { someValue } = attributes;

    return (
        <PanelBody
            className="child-component-settings"
            initialOpen={ true }
        >
            <FormTokenField
                ref={ ref }
                label={ __( 'Label text', 'text-domain' ) }
                value={ someValue }
                suggestions={ suggestions }
                onChange={ ( newValue ) => setAttributes( { someValue: newValue } ) }
            />
        </PanelBody>
    );
};

export default forwardRef( ChildComponent );
```